# Parse.com REST API query format with Angular with include/limit/count

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform

I have tried a few different methods to get filtered data back from the REST API but cannot figure out the correct formatting for queries.  This work for me:

```
var query = encodeURIComponent('where=' + '{"' + type + '":"' + subtype + '"}');

      $http.get('https://api.parse.com/1/classes/events?' + query,
             {headers:{
                'X-Parse-Application-Id': PARSE_CREDENTIALS.APP_ID,
                'X-Parse-REST-API-Key':PARSE_CREDENTIALS.REST_API_KEY,
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            }
          })
    },
```

But when trying to include the additional parameters such as 'include', 'limit', and 'count' I have tried many iterations, but to no avail.  Most queires returned a bad response, however this query returns an empty array (which isn't what I would like, but at least it returned something):

```
var query = encodeURIComponent('where=' + '{"' + type + '":"' + subtype + '", "limit":2}')
```

I have also tried using a params object with Angular's $http object but even with the same formatting as the above query, it returns a bad response.  Can anyone give me the correct formatting for this as well?  This, for example, does not seem to work:

```
   $http.get('https://api.parse.com/1/classes/events',
                     {params: {"where" : encodeURIComponent('{"senses":"touch"}') }},
                     {headers:{
                        'X-Parse-Application-Id': PARSE_CREDENTIALS.APP_ID,
                        'X-Parse-REST-API-Key':PARSE_CREDENTIALS.REST_API_KEY,
                        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                    }
                  })
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why aren't using Parse.com [Javascript API](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide)?

Comment: Attempting to be platform agnostic - going with the Javascript API would be a last-resort I suppose.

Comment: You should create a service to abstract away all these $http calls from the controller anyway. That will also make it "platform agnostic".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are "overthinking" this since a lot of the problems with encoding are quite common and have the benefit of being already solved. So, you don't need to do string formatting/encoding with `$http` - just use objects.

Also, after checking [parse.com API](https://parse.com/docs/rest#queries-counting), `limit`, `count` and `include` are siblings of `where` - not children.

So, all you need to do is:

```
var whereQuery = {type: subtype};

$http.get('https://api.parse.com/1/classes/events',
   {
     headers: {
                'X-Parse-Application-Id': PARSE_CREDENTIALS.APP_ID,
                'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': PARSE_CREDENTIALS.REST_API_KEY,
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
              },
     params:  { 
                 where: whereQuery,
                 limit: 2,
                 // count: 1
                 // include: "something"
              }
   });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - much appreciated - unfortunately it's still not working for me.

`return $http.get('https://api.parse.com/1/classes/events',
     
           {
           headers:{
                    'X-Parse-Application-Id': PARSE_CREDENTIALS.APP_ID,
                    'X-Parse-REST-API-Key':PARSE_CREDENTIALS.REST_API_KEY,
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                },
                 params: {where : {senses:"touch", limit:2} }
              })
`


returns an empty array.  If I remove limit:2 from the object, it works and returns all objects. Any ideas?

Comment: I think `limit` shouldn't be part of `where`... but that is beyond the scope of your question and my answer

Comment: I agree it doesn't make sense to put it inside of the where statement - I'm trying to figure out how to format it so that you can have a where statement with other parameters.  Is it to use an ampersand, multiple objects, etc..?

Comment: @JohnMastri, I updated the answer. Hopefully it's enough to understand the principles of how this works, and that with `$http` you don't need to do the kind of formatting/encoding that you tried in your question

Comment: Thanks - was definitely making it hard than it needed to be. =)