# Parse.com REST API - Skip and limit query in javascript

Tags: angularjs, rest, parse-platform

I'm trying to get some data with parse by using the REST API in Javascript.

All works well until I try to add a limit and an offset ("skip").

[Here](https://parse.com/docs/rest#queries-constraints), there is the doc to use the parameters with a REST API but only with curl or python.
With [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26498598/parse-com-rest-api-query-format-with-angular-with-include-limit-count) I try to do something like this :

```
$http.post('https://api.parse.com/1/functions/expressions', option, {
    headers: {
        'X-Parse-Application-Id': 0123456789,
        'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': 9876543210,
        'Content-Type':'application/json'
    },
    params: {
        'limit': limitValue,
        'skip': skipValue 
    }
});
```

But this only return me the 10th first result even when I increment the skip param.

Does someone have an idea to use this parameters in javascript ?

Comment: Curious as to why you're using the REST API instead of the JavaScript SDK?

Comment: I'm using the REST API instead of the javascript SDK because my project will be app for ios platform and (cordova) and I already try with the javascript SDK but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling a Cloud Code function via the REST API here so the documentation doesn't really apply here in terms of the parameters you use unless your function does implement passing through the skip/limit parameter to the query you are doing in your function. Otherwise they will simply be ignored.

Comment: Thank you, after looking the function in Cloud Code I found how to use my parameters.

Comment: How you fixed this issue?I am facing the same problem.